# NSTimer not calling Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nstimer

I have an NSTimer that should call a method every second, but it doesn't seem to be calling it at all.

This is how I declare the timer:

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeManager:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This is the method it calls:

```
-(void) fadeManager: (NSTimer*) timer{
    NSLog(@"IT'S WORKING!");
    self.playHead += .1; // keeps track of where they are in full track
    if (self.playHead >= self.wait  && ![player isPlaying]) { // checks if wait is over
        [player play];
    }
    if (self.playHead >= self.duration + self.startTime && [player isPlaying]) { // checks if full duration is over
        [player pause];
        [self reset];
    }
    int fadeOutArea = self.startTime + self.duration - self.fadeOut;
    int fadeInArea = self.startTime + self.fadeIn;
    if (self.playHead <= fadeInArea && [player volume] < relativeVolume) { // checks if fadingIn.
        [self fadeInIncriment];
    }
    if (self.playHead >= fadeOutArea  && [player volume] > 0) {
        [self fadeOutIncriment];
    }
}
```

The code was not working so I put the NSLog in as well as a break point. It seems that it is never being called. Why is this? Does it matter that I declared the method in the .m file like this:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface CueMusic ()

- (void) delayFadeOut: (AVAudioPlayer*) dFade;
- (void) fadeInIncriment;
- (void) fadeOutIncriment;
- (void) fadeManager: (NSTimer*) timer; // <--------
- (void) start;

@end

@implementation CueMusic
 .......
```

Comment: This is not even remotely related to Xcode.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Either use

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeManager:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

or

```
//schedules the timer
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeManager:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

#### From the docs [Scheduling Timers in Run Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-SW1)

> - Use the [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:) or [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) class method to create the timer and schedule it on the current run loop in the default mode.
> - Use the [`timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:) or [`timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) class method to create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling the addTimer:forMode: method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)

---

#### Swift Code

Either

```
let timer: NSTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "fadeManager:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

Or

```
//schedules the timer
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "fadeManager:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Ohhh... I must have selected the wrong method in the xcode suggestion thingawhatever. I meant to call the second one.

Comment: I've done it too, and I've seen this same question several times.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that when using `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, the resulting timer does not automatically get added to the run loop. I would recommend using `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` instead, which performs this step for you.

If you prefer to use `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` then you need to manually add the timer to the current run loop. To do this, call `NSRunLoop`'s `addTimer:forMode:` method. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:tTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire the timer.

You can do it by adding it to a thread:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeManager:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

or calling

```
[timer fire];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```